# 74HC595 to 4 Digit 7 Segment using SevSegShift Library

Tags: arduino-uno, shift-register, 7-segment

I have a question regarding the use of [SevSegShift](https://github.com/bridystone/SevSegShift) library. I followed the example properly and tested it to see if it works. It was able to power up the seven segments and light up the whole LEDs (even the decimal) but it's not showing the output I want to show.

Based on the code below, I want to show the number 500 but it does not. Even tried `sevsegshift.setChars("abcd")`, no change.

This is my code:

```
#include <SevSegShift.h>

#define SHIFT_PIN_SHCP 6
#define SHIFT_PIN_STCP 5
#define SHIFT_PIN_DS   4

SevSegShift sevseg(SHIFT_PIN_DS, SHIFT_PIN_SHCP, SHIFT_PIN_STCP, 1, true);

void setup() {
  byte numDigits = 4;
  byte digitPins[] = {9, 10, 11, 12}; // These are the PINS of the ** Arduino **
  byte segmentPins[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}; // these are the PINs of the ** Shift register **
  bool resistorsOnSegments = false; // 'false' means resistors are on digit pins
  byte hardwareConfig = COMMON_CATHODE; // See README.md for options
  bool updateWithDelays = false; // Default 'false' is Recommended
  bool leadingZeros = false; // Use 'true' if you'd like to keep the leading zeros
  bool disableDecPoint = true; // Use 'true' if your decimal point doesn't exist or isn't connected
  
  sevseg.begin(hardwareConfig, numDigits, digitPins, segmentPins, resistorsOnSegments, updateWithDelays, leadingZeros, disableDecPoint);
  sevseg.setBrightness(10);
}

void loop() {
  sevseg.setNumber(500);
  //delay(1000);
  sevseg.refreshDisplay(); // Must run repeatedly; don't use blocking code (ex: delay()) in the loop() function or this won't work right
}
```

This is my breadboard schematic down below.

[image: Breadboard]

(220 ohm resistors on the digit pins and the segment pins are connected to the shift register)

Comment: See the comment of the last statement. It says, don't use blocking code in the for loop e.g. `delay()` and one line above you use delay(). Hmmm, possibly ?! The shift register must be update very fast i guess.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer Thank you, that was an oversight on my part. Took out the `delay()` and still the same output :(

Comment: Did you connect +5V and Ground to the breadboard? Your schematic doesn’t show them.

Comment: @StarCat Yep! I'm sorry I forgot that part. Will edit it :D

Comment: OK, for me this was the most obvious possibillity of failure. But there are more. A brightness of 10 seems very low to me (max is 100). If you have COMMON_ANODE LED-Bars but you have configured COMMON_CATHODEs this would invert the brightness. Dark is Bright and Bright is Dark. Take this together and i might result in your observations. And probably the wiring is not correct. If you add a picture to the post we could check it. Btw. pin 12 can not provide PWM output (no ~ symbol), so it can not be used to regulate the brighness of the connected digit.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer That actually made a lot of sense! I changed it to `COMMON_ANODE` and set brightness to 100 so that I don't need to change pin 12. That helped a lot! The only problem now is that the display is showing in reverse and the decimal point is showing even if I set the `disableDecPoint` to `true` but I was able to fix that by reversing the digit pins and also setting `disableDecPoint` to `false`. I will put the updated code and also some picture output :D

Comment: swap the digit selection pins

Comment: Please forget the last sentence in my last comment. I've looked intio the lib code and they do not use PWM to control the brightness. Instead they use custom method the controll the brightness over the on and of time of an LED.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer, PWM wit 595?

Comment: @Juraj. If you controll the backpath (digit selector pins) it should work. Of cause the shift register can not be used for PWM ;-).  And yes, their custom method is far more clever then PWM. I have to admit.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer, PWM on digit selection pins? it makes even more less sense. only one digit can be lit at time. the redraw is fast lighting up digits one by one. the time between the redraws determines the brightness of the display

Comment: @Juraj As I wrote it is not a clever alternative but it depends an the speed of the PWM if it is possible or not. I admit, the idea of PWM is not the best one I had, and also it would be better if I try to think before I write. ;-)

Comment: hello i made this but i have question how we can turn on dots??

Comment: this program and wiring god but i cant find a way to turn on decimal point with numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally able to fix it with the help of @PeterPaulKiefer, I was able to find the problem. The problem is in the code itself (schematic is alright. No changes there) and this is the updated code.

```
#include <SevSegShift.h>

#define SHIFT_PIN_SHCP 6
#define SHIFT_PIN_STCP 5
#define SHIFT_PIN_DS   4

SevSegShift sevseg(SHIFT_PIN_DS, SHIFT_PIN_SHCP, SHIFT_PIN_STCP, 1, true);

void setup() {
  byte numDigits = 4;
  byte digitPins[] = {12, 11, 10, 9}; // These are the PINS of the ** Arduino **
  byte segmentPins[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}; // these are the PINs of the ** Shift register **
  bool resistorsOnSegments = false; // 'false' means resistors are on digit pins
  byte hardwareConfig = COMMON_ANODE; // See README.md for options
  bool updateWithDelays = false; // Default 'false' is Recommended
  bool leadingZeros = false; // Use 'true' if you'd like to keep the leading zeros
  bool disableDecPoint = false; // Use 'true' if your decimal point doesn't exist or isn't connected
  
  sevseg.begin(hardwareConfig, numDigits, digitPins, segmentPins, resistorsOnSegments, updateWithDelays, leadingZeros, disableDecPoint);
  sevseg.setBrightness(100);
}

void loop() {
  sevseg.setNumber(500);
  sevseg.refreshDisplay(); // Must run repeatedly; don't use blocking code (ex: delay()) in the loop() function or this won't work right
}
```

**What changed:**

1. Turns out my 7-segment is `COMMON_ANODE` so I changed my `hardwareConfig`
2. Set brightness to 100
   (At this point, it shows the number in reverse but with a decimal point in each digit)
3. Set `disableDecPoint` to `false`
   (At this point, the display is showing but in reverse but no more decimal point)
   [image: reverse]
4. To fix this, I set the `digitPins[]` in reverse and it now shows the proper format
   [image: Correct Output]

Thank you so much Peter for helping me figure out what's wrong!

Also the LED Bar I use is [4-Digit 0.36" LED, 7-segments display, common-anode](https://store.createlabz.com/products/40-005?_pos=3&_sid=cf5299bd3&_ss=r). (The link is to the shop I got it from)